# maven can't download dependency Illegal character in path

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory

The problem I'm facing here is that i can't download a pom from the local artifactory. (the pom is there)

To give a short overview about the projects i'm dealing with:

- first of all there are 2 projects
- one is the base project and there i declared in the parent pom the version like this:

  `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>x.x.x.x</groupId>
      <artifactId>x</artifactId>
      <version>${global.version}</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      ...
      <properties>
         <global.version>x.x.x-SNAPSHOT</global.version>
       </properties>
    </project>`
- the other one is declared the same way

now in the second project there is a dependency to the first project and if i want to build it there is an error popping up

> Illegal character in path at index 29: URL/artifactory/x/x/x/x/x/x/${global.version}/x-${global.version}.pom

i know it is telling me to eliminate the `${global.version}` but is there an other way to fix this up?

Comment: Is that property declared in both projects?

Comment: @Pablo yes, both projects have a parent pom.xml with the `global.version` property (they are on different versions)

Comment: @Mofty what's the use of declaring it a property if it's different in each project anyway? Can't you use the `${project.version}` default property?

Comment: @AndréStannek there are 2 different maven projects. like the first one has 1 parent pom and 10 child and the 2. one has one parent pom and 5 child because they are physically separated so i don't want to go into all 11 or 6 poms for the next release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it up some how...

The main problem here was the artifactory i think.

Whenever i deployed the maven project 1 to the artifactory there where these relative version instructions `${global.version}` still written in the pom.
That's why every time project 2 wants to load the dependency it cant find the path.

So it's back to standard version declaration.